# How can I startup my cinder application in a maximized state?

Tags: c++, cinder

how can I startup my cinder application in windows in a maximized state? I see some documentation about ShowWindow SW_MAXIMIZED but don't see how this is supported in cinder, can anyone offer any help?

Answer (score 3):

This works in OS X and I assume in Windows as well to start an app in a fullscreen state, if that's what you're looking for:

```
class MyApp : public ci::app::AppNative
{
  public:
    void prepareSettings( Settings *settings )
    {
      settings->setFullScreen();
    }
    ...
};
```

P.S. I see more Cinder related activity in the [Cinder forums](http://forum.libcinder.org/) than on StackOverflow :)